# Working with list and databases in Flutter

Tags: database, list, flutter, data-manipulation

I guess this will be a quick question but as the title says im working with lists and my main concern is when I store said list in a database I want to be able to read and manipulate it.

What is the best database to work with lists?

Note: I have tried firebase realtime and firestore but when it comes to trying to manipulate the data such as using the contains() method to filter, I won't let me do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The best database" is a relative term, it depends on your project and structure. You can either use MySQL or NoSQL databases like Mongo, Cassandra etc. you need to decide. But the recommending way of this in production is, doing database operations in a server/back-end system. You will have your database connection and operations in your service and call them with REST APIs. Your functions will handle your lists and make operations to your db. If you don't want to struggle with a service and you will not make your project to development, the fastest way could be firebase and cloud databases. Also, you can connect to MySQL with flutter. It is about your functions/methods to manipulate the data.